# How to embed dynamic OR condition after WHERE statement in linq query c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, collections

I have a LINQ query like this:

```
    var getOnlyMP = from mpPoint in cmList where 
    mpPoint.Component.Contains("asd") || 
    mpPoint.Component.Contains("dsa") || 
    mpPoint.Component.Contains("123") || 
    mpPoint.Component.Contains("456")                                            
    select new MP
    {
        MPName = mpPoint.Component,
        X = mpPoint.PlaceX,
        Y = mpPoint.PlaceY,                                 
    };
```

I want to store "asd", "dsa", "123", "456" in an array, so is there a possibility to loop through on that array and make the comparing in all items after the WHERE clause dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) with an array,

```
var expectedStrings = new string[] {"asd", "dsa", "123", "456"};

var getOnlyMP = cmList.Where(mpPoint=> 
        expectedStrings.Any(x => mpPoint.Component.Contains(x)))
        .Select(x => new MP
                {
                   MPName = x.Component,
                   X = x.PlaceX,
                   Y = x.PlaceY,                                 
                });
```

In query  form,

```
var expectedStrings = new string[] {"asd", "dsa", "123", "456"};
var getOnlyMP = from mpPoint in cmList where 
   expectedStrings.Any(x => mpPoint.Component.Contains(x)))             
   select new MP
   {
      MPName = mpPoint.Component,
      X = mpPoint.PlaceX,
      Y = mpPoint.PlaceY,                                 
   };
```

Comment: @dba, silly mistake from my end. I fixed it please look at updated answer and thanks for your comment

Comment: I was sure, it's been just a typo, but I couldn't edit, therefore the comment :-)